# RoR Active Records undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I created 2 models User and Server but when I tried to add a data to Server I cannot get the result that I want. When I tried this on Rails Console I am not getting any errors. This is making my head crazy for 2 days now. Tried lots of things.

user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :server
end
```

User Migration

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.integer :channel_id
      t.timestamps

    end
  end
end
```

server.rb

```
class Server < ApplicationRecord
has_many :user
end
```

Server Migration

```
class CreateServers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :servers do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

My Controller:

```
def alert(args)
 @server =  Server.where(name: args)
   if @server == []
     Server.create(name: args)
     respond_with :message, text: t('.bildirim_on')
   else
   end
     @user = @server.user.create(channel_id: 215682104)
end
```

I am getting this error:

```
  Server Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "servers".* FROM "servers" WHERE "servers"."name" = ?  [["name", "videoyun"]]
Completed in 28ms (ActiveRecord: 0.8ms)
undefined method `user' for #<Server::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00000004dae158>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `@server` is an `ActiveRecord_Relationship`, not a `Server` instance. You should use `Server.find_by(name: args)` and check if is `.present?` before creating it (it will return a Server instance or nil, instead of an ActiveRecord Relationship).

Also you should assign to `@server` the new one within the if statement.

Comment: This one working. But why `Server.where(name: *args)` not working and `Server.find_by` working. I still couldn't understand the difference between them.

Comment: Its because `where` returns an "array" of servers (its not an array instance, but is similar to), and `find_by` returns one instance of server (instead of an "array").

Answer (score 0):

```
class Server < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :user
end
```

`:user` should be `:users`